# Box2D Typecast: ApplyForce() anti gravity

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm having a typecast issue here and I've been breaking my head over it for the entire day. The issue is with the ApplyForce Function. We aren't able to multiply the b2Vec2 (gravity) with the float(mass). I've followed the example [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4653/intermediate-box2d-physics-forces-ray-casts-and-sensors) Can someone please help me?

```
-(void) antiGravity
{
float32 total_mass = [cannonBallBody getMass];
b2Vec2 point0 = [cannonBallBody getWorldCenter: cannonBallBody];
cannonBallBody -> ApplyForce(-1 * world -> GetGravity() * total_mass, cannonBallBody -> GetWorldCenter());
}
```

With the CannonBallBody of type b2Body* and the

```
- (float) getMass{
float total_mass = 0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            total_mass+= body1[i]-> GetMass();
    }
return total_mass;
 }

- (b2Vec2) getWorldCenter: (b2Body*)body{
    return body->GetWorldCenter();
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question because you didn't say what error this is causing.

But I would guess that you just need to put the float before the vector. The reason is that Box2D defines this operator, but not the reverse:

```
inline b2Vec2 operator * (float32 s, const b2Vec2& a)
{
    return b2Vec2(s * a.x, s * a.y);
}
```